# Referencing screen pixels

Tags: pixel

I've been looking all over the internet for an answer to this but so far haven't been coming across anything helpful. I'm using Visual Basic although by question could pertain to any programming language.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is simply to set the properties of a specific screen pixel. I can use something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the position and RGB values of a screen pixel but I haven't found a way of changing them. SetPixel works well for images, but I'm trying to do something more general than that. For example, inverting the RGB values of your desktop, or creating a mirror image of it.

I have a feeling that there is an easy answer to this but nonetheless I still haven't been able to figure it out!

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. Pixels cannot directly be changed in most OS-s, because the color of a givel pixel may not be determined by a single application. Consider multiple overlapping windows - if the background window tries to change a pixel within (or outside) its bounds, should the top window's contents change?

Comment: Your linked method (GetPixel) doens't return the color of a _screen_ pixel - it returns the color of a pixel of a bitmap, which is about the best you can do. For such operations, you need to acquire a bitmap, change it and then render it to the screen using OS API-s.

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps what would work is if the window simply made a copy of what is displayed on the screen behind it (appropriately adjusting the resolution of course). 

I'm using this

`Dim myBmp As New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp) gr.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, myBmp.Size) 
gr.Dispose()`

 to make a bitmap out of the screen.

Comment: You can get a screen bitmap like that but you can't put it back on top of other windows (not in a functional way). You can't affect what the contents of a window is outside of your application.

Comment: Then how does something like the "share deesktop" function in skype work?